# Why I can't return nothing in a static method this way

Tags: java, return, static-methods

I wrote a piece of code just to train a litte bit and I wanted to understand why I cannot use this notation.

```
public static double retangleArea (double c, double d) {
  double area = c * d;
  if ( c < 0 || d < 0) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
    return;
  }
  return area;
}
```

If I call this method in my main() it will shout "Error." and still calculate (c * d) with a negative number but I wanted just the print to show in. Well, I know how to get rid of this problem I just want to understand why I can't do this way and what's the problem with that.

Comment: You declared your method as returning `double`, so you have to return a `double`.  If you want to only sometimes return a value, take a look at [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Alternately you can validate your input and throw an exception if c or d is < 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411974/what-does-return-mean-at-the-end-of-a-void-method

Answer (score 4):

Three ways round this:

1. `throw` an exception rather than writing an error to the console. You could write to the console in a `catch` block where you are arguably in a better position to deal with the error.
2. Change the function return type to `Double` (note the capital), and return `null` if you don't want to calculate a value.
3. Use `java.lang.Optional<T>` as the return type.

Of these, I prefer and therefore recommend 1.

Comment: So basically when I declare a double method I'm obligated to return double values and if the statement doesn't obbey my conditions I can throw an exception in order to not change my method type. Is it right?

Comment: Exactly that. Use the exception mechanism for dealing with unexpected situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `return;` if the method returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is `public static double` this means you have to return double in any case. You can make it `public static void` and pass value to field of class.